# How do I create multiple rows of my aliens on my screen while building the space invaders game?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, group

I have successfully created a row of my aliens in the space invaders game. However, after writing the code to fill up my screen with several columns of these rows and I run the code, I still don't get it right.

```
game_function.py
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    # make the most recently drawn screen visible

    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    pygame.display.flip()

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit into the screen"""
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows


def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    """create an alien and place it in a row"""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)


def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row"""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens"""
    # create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row
    # spacing between each alien is equal to one alien width
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
                                  alien.rect.height)
    # create the first row of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            # create an alien and place it in a row
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
```

```
main.py
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from pygame.sprite import Group
from alien import Alien


def run_game():
    # initialize
    # pygame, settings
    # and screen
    # object

    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    # make a ship
    ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)
    # group to store bullets
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    # make an alien
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    # a group to store aliens
    aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
    # create a fleet of aliens
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

    # main loop for the game
    while True:
        # watch
        # for keyboard and mouse events
        gf.check_events(ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)


run_game()
```

So in essence my question is, how can I get just this my single row of aliens into columns of aliens to populate my screen. From my code, it should generate a fleet of aliens but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run this code because some of the files are missing. The way I would approach fixing it would be to first look at whether functions like get_number_aliens_x and get_number_rows are returning the correct values. If those are correct, the next step would be to verify that the aliens are indeed created in the correct places, and are remaining in the correct places. I can't see anything particularly wrong in create_alien, but could there be code in the Alien class which is messing up their positions after they've been created?

Comment: this is the alien.py code

Comment: This is still not enough to run the program because it is missing ship.py and settings.py. Is this a program you've written yourself from scratch, or is it something you're adapting or copying from somewhere else? Rather than rely on others to fix it for you, I would suggest following the advice I gave in my initial answer about ways of tracking down the problem. I can see that there's nothing in the alien.py file to make the aliens move, so you will want to check (e.g. by printing the values) that they are being correctly placed to begin with, and check values such as number of rows.